# How to find bounds of an array with unlimited size

Tags: c++, arrays

Recently I have faced this question in an interview.

I have to write a function(with parameters, a pointer to the start of the sorted array of unknown size and number which is to be find) to find the index of the given number.If the given element is not present in the array, I have to return -1.

I was actually trying for log(n) solution.

My idea is look for the element at index-2 of the array.If the  element at the index-2 is less than the given number, look at index-4,if the element is still less look at index 8 and soon.

So basically the idea is to increase the value of i from 2 to j where arr[j]>given number and then do binary search on arr[j/2] and arr[j].

But then I got stuck on how to handle the case where the given element is not present in the array.

How to handle this case in c++ as I don't think c++ will catch out of bound exception?

Any ideas would really help...

Comment: I think the algorithm would crucially depend on what happens when you try to access an element that's out of bounds. Did you ask the interviewer that? If you did, please edit their answer into the question.

Comment: This technique is called [exponential search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search).

Comment: If you don't know the size, you can't possibly avoid going beyond the end.

Comment: You have to know the size of the array, or you are looking UDB right in the face.

Comment: Is there a sentinel guard for the end of array (as null terminated string) ?

Comment: Unlimited size cannot mean unknowable size and the question be sensible.

Comment: @NPE I did ask them..Unfortunately he said anything can happen..

Comment: will java catch out of bound exception?

Comment: @starkk92: "Unfortunately he said anything can happen" Did he also say it can kill your dog?  Undefined Behavior.  It's a BS question.  As this was "an interview" question, run.  Take the next job.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Not necessarily. One possible setup could be that the array is always terminated by `+infinity` (or other sentinel value known in advance). Thus a linear search would know when to stop, but an exponential search would have difficulty avoiding going past the end of the array. This is where asking the interviewer for clarification would be crucial.

Comment: "will java catch out of bound exception?" who cares?  you tagged with 'c++'

Comment: @starkk92: Then the next question should have been what is supposed to happen if the number we're looking for is larger than every element of the array. How is the algorithm to avoid going past the end of the array?

Comment: @NPE Fair point. I was assuming we had all the available info - which is generally a mistake.

Comment: @AlanStokes: In my experience, underspecified questions tend to get asked in interviews for two reasons: (1) the interviewer have not thought through the question themselves; (2) it's a deliberate tactic to see how the interviewee would deal with ambiguity. Either way, the only winning strategy is to ask questions. :-)

Comment: @NPE: this was tagged as a c++ question.  Where is `+infinity` defined in C++?  Or are you suggesting floating point indices are somehow valid within the Standard (good luck with that)?  If the OP is asking about a question for a C++ job, he should just say "this question cannot be answered."  I don't care if "language X" has other facilities.  For C++, without knowing the array size (i.e. getting it as one of the parameters), this question cannot be answered.  End of story.

Comment: @NPE: "(1) the interviewer have not thought through the question themselves;" I'm in total agreement with you on this.  Unfortunately, in many cases this can also be "has no idea what a valid answer actually is."

Comment: @frasnian: I won't debate the issue of numeric values. What I would say is that, when I deliberately pose an underspecified problem to an interviewee, I am not very impressed if their answer is "This cannot be answered. End of story." In fact, I wouldn't be very impressed if this was their answer to *any* of my questions. :-)

Comment: @NPE: good point.  I should have phrased this as "This cannot be answered, and *this is why*..." As an interviewer, this is an open opportunity for the candidate to show knowledge outside of rote questions.

Answer (score 0):

just get size with this function if available in your runtime and the memory was allocated in the heap

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc.aspx

and do simple binary search

if you would like to ensure the number is in the array (this is not needed in this case but giving you as general case hint) you can replace some in the array if mutable with a sentinel (to avoid resize).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an log(n) solution when you don't know the size of the array. What you can do is a simple linear search. The key here is that the array is sorted, that means that if you find an item bigger than the one you're looking for the item is not in this array.

Iterate until either A) you find the item you're looking for or B) you find an element that is bigger than the item you're looking for. If A) return the current index, if B) return -1.

Comment: you can't do that linear search since A) you have no guarantee you are going to find the item your looking for and B) you have no guarantee that you are gonna find an element that is bigger than the item you are looking for. How about looking for the number 5 in an array filled with zeroes for instance? The array *is* sorted!

Comment: An option could be to put the elements at the end of the array to make sure they exist, but you don't know the size of the array. There is the problem.